# Break sequence with Cisco devices

Tags: cisco-nexus

I am not able to send a break sequence from my HP pro book laptop to Cisco Nexus 9000 series switch over a usb adapter and Cisco console cable.

I tried every possible button combination.

I do not understand who is making the problem? Is it my laptop vendor? Is it Windows 7? Is SecureCRT or Putty? Is it Cisco switch?

Comment: <CTRL><SHFT>6 Other than that, we need more information.

Comment: When I use SecureCRT on W10, I use Ctrl-Break

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised `<CTRL> + <BREAK>` isn't working in SecureCRT.  That is the typical key combination for it.

Cisco has a [helpful list of break hotkeys](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/routers/10000-series-routers/12818-61.html) for a lot of terminal software.  PuTTY isn't in the list, but it has a **menu command** for sending a break sequence.